# How can I mock a method throwing an exception which uses the parameter in the exception message?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Mocking an interface `ISomething` with method `Task<List<int>> GetIdsAsync(int)` I can do the following to use the parameter in generating the return:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.GetIdsAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((int n) => new List<int>(n));
```

I can also mock the method throwing an exception:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.GetIdsAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .ThrowsAsync(new InvalidOperationException());
```

But I would actually like to `throw new InvalidOperationException($"{n} is not valid");` using the input parameter to generate the error message in the exception.

I cannot figure out what the syntax would be for this, assuming of course that it is possible?

I tried:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.GetIdsAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .ThrowsAsync((int n) => new InvalidOperationException($"{n} is not valid"));
```

Which seemed reasonable but gives a somewhat complex error

```
 CS1929 'ISetup<ISomething, Task<List<int>>>' does not contain a
 definition for 'ThrowsAsync' and the best extension method overload
 'SequenceExtensions.ThrowsAsync(ISetupSequentialResult<Task>,
 Exception)' requires a receiver of type 'ISetupSequentialResult<Task>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this answer, there is currently no `ThrowsAsync` that takes a value function similar to `ReturnsAsync`. All take `Exception` as the argument.

A work around would be to create a local variable, capture the input parameter in a callback and use that in the throw.

```
//...

int n = 0;
mock
    .Setup(_ => _.GetIdsAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Callback((int arg) => n = arg)
    .ThrowsAsync(new InvalidOperationException($"{n} is not valid"));

//...
```

Comment: What am I misunderstanding that my attempt doesn't work and this initial step is needed - why is it different to using the input in the return?

Comment: @Mr.Boy there is currently no `ThrowsAsync` that takes a value function similar to `ReturnsAsync`. You could possibly try to write your own or make a feature request to the repo.

Comment: oh OK so it simply isn't provided, not a fundamental misunderstanding on my part. Thanks.